# Segmentation fault (core dumped) from command line argument

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to run some code from terminal using arguments. Here's my code:

```
int PORT_NUM = 0;
int BYTES_TO_SEND = 0;
char* LocalAddresss = "";


char* concat(char *s1, char *s2)
{
    char *result = malloc(strlen(s1)+strlen(s2)+1);
    strcpy(result, s1);
    strcat(result, s2);
    return result;
}

void error(const char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sockfd, portno, n;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    struct hostent *server;

    char buffer[256];
    char data[BYTES_TO_SEND];

    LocalAddresss = concat("192.168.1.",argv[1]);
    PORT_NUM = atoi(argv[2]);
    BYTES_TO_SEND = atoi(argv[3]);

    fflush(stdout);

    for(int i = 0; i < BYTES_TO_SEND; i++){
        data[i] = 'Z';
    }

    char* message_to_send = data;

    portno = PORT_NUM;
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0) 
        error("ERROR opening socket");

    server = gethostbyname(LocalAddresss);
    if (server == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no such host\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    bcopy((char *)server->h_addr, 
         (char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,
         server->h_length);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);

    if (connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
        error("ERROR connecting");

    while(1){
        n = write(sockfd,message_to_send,strlen(message_to_send));
    }

    close(sockfd);
    return 0;
}
```

My issue is this. The following works: `./TCP_client 16 2000 100` on the command line.

This doesn't: `./TCP_client 16 2000 3000`

I get "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"

Are there restrictions on the number of total bytes in command line arguments or something? How can I resolve this issue?

After running this with GDB it says "Program received signal SIGBUS, Bus error.0x0000000100000ccf in main ()" Not really sure what this is though.

Comment: c doesn't have limits on command line argument sizes. that's imposed by your shell. You need to show what this `concat` function is doing. That's not a standard C function. string concatenation is done by `strcat`. And since your failing one is one char longer than the other, you probably have an overflow somewhere.

Comment: did u run it under a debugger - that will show you where its crashing

Comment: @VishnuMurale Is that the _full_ code? What headers are you including?

Comment: compile the code with -g then run it under GDB and please fix the v serious bug I show in my answer

Answer (score 1):

this fails becuase you are declaring data with a size of 0

```
int BYTES_TO_SEND = 0;
...
char data[BYTES_TO_SEND];
'''
LocalAddresss = concat("192.168.1.",argv[1]);
PORT_NUM = atoi(argv[2]);
BYTES_TO_SEND = atoi(argv[3]);
```

you need to move the lines around

```
int BYTES_TO_SEND = 0;
...
LocalAddresss = concat("192.168.1.",argv[1]);
PORT_NUM = atoi(argv[2]);
BYTES_TO_SEND = atoi(argv[3]);
char data[BYTES_TO_SEND];
'''
```

but this is a bad plan - putting a big buffer like that on the stack, better to malloc it. Your example will work, but its not a good design

Comment: This doesn't fix my issue. Also, the fact that this works "./TCP_client 16 2000 100" and this doesn't "./TCP_client 16 2000 3000" makes me think the issue lies elsewhere.

Comment: you are getting undefined behavior, things will randomly work and randomly fail. YOur code may have other bugs in it but this is for sure a serious bug. DID U RUN IT UNDER A DEBUGGER?

Comment: I stand corrected. I think I must have forgot to recompile with your edits, but this seemed to fix it. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

If i were you i would use from the string.h library the strcat() function.

```
#include <string.h>
...
char LocalAddresss[15] = "192.168.1.";
strcat(LocalAddress, argv[1]);
```

Comment: what do you mean by not enought array??

Comment: Not enough array *size*. The initialised value is already taking `11`.

Comment: Now explicity writing beyond the array (only in comment) but more dangerous than safe.